# Having error "undefinned reference to 'LZ4_compressBound' and 'LZ4_compress_default'

Tags: c, linux, lz4

I try to use lz4 compress and decompress in my own C code.
I include"lz4.h" from the downloaded file.
But it still shows undefined references when I try to use the functions.
I am using codeblocks, and I move the lz4.h file to the same folder of my project. I also create the PATH of the lib file which includes lz4.h(it is from Github "lz4_dev")

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "lz4.h"




int main()
{
    time_t start,end;
    int compress, decompress;
    int num_f=0;
    int i;

    const char* const src;
    int srcSize=16385;
    int dstCapacity = LZ4_compressBound(srcSize);
    char* compressed_data = malloc((size_t)dstCapacity);


    FILE * fc;


    num_f = splitFile("/home/ziruo/research/test.txt",16384);

    start = time(NULL);
    for( i = 1; i <= num_f; i++)
    {

        fc = fopen(("/home/ziruo/research/text.txt.%03d",i),"r");
        fgets(src,16384,fc);
        printf("%s",src);
        LZ4_compress_default(src,compressed_data,srcSize,dstCapacity);

    }
    //LZ4LIB_API int LZ4_compress_default(const char* src, char* dst, int srcSize, int dstCapacity);

    end = time(NULL);

    compress=difftime(end,start);
    printf("%d",compress);
    //printf("%d\n",splitFile("/home/ziruo/research/test.txt",16384));




    return 0;
```

Comment: Are you linking with liblz4?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Please show us how you compile you code

Comment: I am trying to linking lz4.h. What I would like to do is use the code to run lz4 in c instead of in Linux terminal.

Comment: I just run it on visual studio.